# Compser is updating with some warnings

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework3

This happens in my mac osx. This is regarding zend framework 3.

When I update the composer some warnings are occur.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.15_8/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.15_8/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

after that when the page is refreshing this error occur.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in /Users/ishara/Documents/workspace/leapx-portal/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 81

Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in /Users/ishara/Documents/workspace/leapx-portal/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 81
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with zendframework 3.

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library mcrypt.so

This is probably caused by not having the PHP [mcrypt](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.setup.php) extension installed.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

According to the [mongodb/mongodb](https://packagist.org/packages/mongodb/mongodb) package, you need to install the PHP [mongodb](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.homebrew.php) extension.